# Is there a document highlighting WPF and Silverlight controls available in the framework?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, controls, diagram

I'm looking for something like a pdf or anything else that would show a chart of available controls in SL and/or WPF.

Ideally, the chart should have a drawing of the control, some succinct description and the hierarchy if possible.

Has anyone seen such a thing? Freeware or Payware, can even be from a book I could buy.

Answer (score 1):

The following MSDN link lists the controls within the Silverlight SDK:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189048(VS.95).aspx

You can try the sdk controls live following this link:

http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/SampleBrowser/#/?sref=HomePage

The controls within the Silverlight Toolkit can be found here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Also, there are plenty of third party controls for Silverlight. The following link contains a list to some of them (free or not):

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/01/28/comprehensive-list-of-silverlight-controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The controls that are shipped with the platform are fairly straightforward, so I'm not sure that would even make sense - i.e. the basic buttons, input box, text block, etc.

As for the controls that are shipped with the Toolkit, which is the richer feature set released out of band in relation to the Silverlight trunk, you can preview everything you asked for here:

http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

What's more, the source code for the preview is included with the tool kit so it's very easy to see how any of those controls were used.

Comment: I know they're straightforward, I'm looking for a kind of cheat sheet of all the available controls.